# How to map ALT-SHIFT-( using AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

Does anyone know how to map SHIFT-ALT-( to the "[" character ?

I've tried using ...

LALT & LSHIFT & (::[

But it throws an error "Invalid hotkey"...

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be LALT+LSHIFT+8???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try

```
<!<+9::Send [
```